# IONIC Improve List Performance

Tags: angular, ionic2

New to Ionic.

I have an array ranging between 0 - 1500 items.
On arrays larger than 400 I notice scrolling\performance issues.
Any advice oh how to improve on this?

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item ="let c of results" (click)="goToClient(c)">
        {{c.FirstName}} {{c.LastName}}
      </button>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="results">
    <ion-item   *virtualItem="let result" (click)="goToClient(result)">
      {{result.FirstName}} {{result.LastName}}
    </ion-item >
  </ion-list>
```